# Joining a single column into two separate columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a `person` table that stores the names of people:

```
personid    firstname   lastname
526         Joe         Burnaby
527         Andy        Brandt
528         Ben         Oxfold
```

These persons are stored in `customer` and `employee` tables

```
customerid  personid
745         526
746         527
```

---

```
employeeid  personid
628         528
```

Then there is a `training` table that stores each column as so

```
trainingid  trainerid   customerid  rating
900         628         745         4
901         628         751         2
```

How can I write a Select that displays both names?
The expected output should be

```
Trainer     Customer    Rating
Ben Oxfold  Joe Burnaby 4
Ben Oxfold  Andy Brandt 2
```

I'm not sure how to go about writing a Select for this, as I bump into a wall in the columns I select:

```
SELECT 
person.firstname||person.lastname AS "Trainer",
person.firstname||person.lastname AS "Customer",
rating
FROM training
JOIN employee ON training.trainerid=employee.employeeid
JOIN customer ON training.customerid=customer.customerid
JOIN person ON employee.personid=person.personid
JOIN person ON customer.personid=person.personid;
```

I tried this, but obviously it will only display whoever you join first in both rows.

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Customer 751 in Training table is not listed in Customer table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the person table two times using alias for the right join clause

```
SELECT   p1.firstname||' '||p1.lastname AS Trainer
       , p2.firstname||' '||p2.lastname AS Customer
       , t.rating
FROM training t 
INNER JOIN  employee e ON e.employeeid = t.trainerid 
INNER JOIN customer c ON c.customerid = t.customerid 
INNER JOIN person p1 ON p1.personid = e.personid 
INNER JOIN person p2 ON p2.personid = c.personid
```